# spawn error in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, spawn

while trying to execute following command using exec

```
java -cp %SIKULI_HOME%\sikuli-script.jar org.python.util.jython E:\automation.sikuli\automation.py "a,b,c"
```

am getting following error

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
```

postreq.params prints values as a,b,c.i want to pass this with \automation.py "a,b,c"
i dodnt know how to pass with below one

```
 exec('java -cp %SIKULI_HOME%\sikuli-script.jar org.python.util.jython E:\automation.sikuli\automation.py postreq.params', function (err, data) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Sikuli execution started")
    //  res.end(data);
  });
```

error

```
{ [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

below command is working properly using `cmd`

```
java -cp %SIKULI_HOME%\sikuli-script.jar org.python.util.jython E:\automation.sikuli\automation.py "a,b,c"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you explain your problem, `postreq.params` seems to be a JavaScript variable. If so, this is what you should exec:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec('java -cp %SIKULI_HOME%\sikuli-script.jar org.python.util.jython E:\automation.sikuli\automation.py "' +  postreq.params + '"', function (err, data) {
```

I'm not a Windows guy so I'm not positive that `%SIKULI_HOME%` will be expanded like you want. If not, then using `process.env.HOMEPATH` like Phoenix suggested in a comment should do the trick:

```
exec('java -cp ' + proces.env.HOMEPATH + '\sikuli-script.jar org.python.util.jython E:\automation.sikuli\automation.py "' +  postreq.params + '"', function (err, data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `execFile` is the *file* to run. You are passing a full set of arguments. Try this:

```
exec('java',  ['-cp', '%SIKULI_HOME%\sikuli-script.jar',
    'org.python.util.jython', 'E:\automation.sikuli\automation.py',
    'postreq.params'], function (err, data) {
```

I'm not sure if it will expand `%SIKULI_HOME%` since I'm not super familiar with Windows.